# linq - Left join with select max and check if record is not null

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 tables:

- customers
- users
- payments

I need to select customers join with users,
left join with payments.
Sometimes I need to check if max record from payment is not null.

I wrote this but it crashes:

I get parameter to this function - byCard

```
from c in _db.Customers
from p in _db.Payments.Where(r => r.CustId == c.ID && r.Success).OrderBy(r =>   r.PaymentDate).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
join u1 in _db.Users on c.UserID equals u1.Id into us
     from use1 in us.DefaultIfEmpty()
&& (byCard == "1" ? p!=null : true)
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it crashes? Do you have an error you can share?

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you use OrderByDescending instead to take the max one out?

Comment: I got into trouble with max and group by. How do I do it?